# Tomcat server.xml redirection: new class files not loaded

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I have have a domain name (for example myapp.com) that I am using it to redirect to a web application (for exmple "myapp"), which is deployed on my tomcat server (for example in "myserver.es/myapp"). I added this fragment to the server.xml file of the tomcat to configure the redirection:

```
<Host name="myapp.com" appBase="webapps/myapp"
   unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
   xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
   <Context path="/" docBase="."/>
   <Alias>www.myapp.com</Alias>
</Host>
```

Apparently it is working good, if I write "mydomain.com" in the browser the app is shown correctly.

The problem: when I generate a new WAR file of that app and I upload it to the Tomcat server (after stopping and undeploying the previous version), the changes related with Java code are not shown. I have to restart my tomcat server to access to the last version of the app from "myapp.com".

In contrast, if I access to "mydomain.com/myapp", I can see the last version of the app, showing the changes made in the last WAR.

So, I think that the problem is related with the redirection. It is anything wrong with the previous XML code?

The other "Host" configured in the server.xml is this one:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've discovered the solution! I needed to set `privileged="true"` inside the Context tag.

Answer (score 1):

You might be having issues with [Parallel Deployement](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment)

You could set `undeployOldVersions="true"` inside your host to see if that works.

Comment: I have tested that, and it doesn't works. I am having that problem only with one app of the Tomcat server, the only which is associated with other domain name (myapp.com).

Comment: As I say before, I can see the latest version of the web application in mydomain.com/myapp, but not if I access to myapp.com

Comment: I have searched the number of appearances of the class files in the server, and the files are not duplicated. So, the problem could be related with the memory?